# Symfony ExceptionHandler throwing an error about itself

Tags: php, symfony, exception, php-7

I'm working on an upgrade of an application to use Symfony 3 and PHP 7. I keep getting this error. I'm not sure where it stems from or how to fix it.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler::handle() must be an instance of Exception

Comment: You need to provide a stack trace, or the code that causes this error to get any assistance.

Comment: Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\ExceptionHandler->handle(Object(Error))
#1 {main}
thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/upgrade/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/ExceptionHandler.php line 67

Answer (score 8):

**TL;DR**: A PHP error is triggered somewhere in your code. In PHP 5, it was triggered as a simple PHP error; in PHP 7 it's thrown as an `Error` that is now passed into Symfony's exception handler.

This error has probably always been in your application and was swallowed due to `error_reporting` or `display_errors` settings.

---

The error handling mechanism changed in PHP 7. Errors are now thrown as instances of the `Error` class and can be caught by an exception handler. See [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php) for more information:

> PHP 7 changes how most errors are reported by PHP. Instead of reporting errors through the traditional error reporting mechanism used by PHP 5, most errors are now reported by throwing Error exceptions.
>
> As with normal exceptions, these `Error` exceptions will bubble up until they reach the first matching catch block. If there are no matching blocks, then any default exception handler installed with `set_exception_handler()` will be called, and if there is no default exception handler, then the exception will be converted to a fatal error and will be handled like a traditional error.

However, note that the `Error` class does not extend the `Exception` class (they both implement the `Throwable` interface, though).

Since the Symfony exception handler was registered as an exception handler using the [`set_exception_handler`](http://php.net/set_exception_handler) method, this handler will be invoked with all kinds of uncaught `Error` instances thrown around in your code, but cannot handle them as it expects an `Exception` per its type hint.

For the time being, you could solve this by implementing your own ExceptionHandler (that you can then use instead of Symfony's) that implements a `handle(Throwable $error)` function, allowing you to also catch PHP Errors.

Comment: but I can't extend the ExceptionHandler, because everything in the class is "private" :/ ... is there a different solution for Symfony 3.4 ?

Comment: I'm trying to fix this in S3.4 and boy is it trial and error... @LarsMoelleken I'm using reference https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/error_pages.html Let me know what your solution was if you remember it.

Comment: @SteveExdia I looked into the old code and I replaced the old logic with a custom "kernel.exception" extension.

Comment: @LarsMoelleken I'm assuming you mean the paragraph (in my error_pages link) starting with "Writing your own event listener for the kernel.exception event": https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/event_dispatcher.html Now I'm up to my eyeballs in documentation suggestions  seeing which works.